# C File Name with multiple periods

Tags: c, fopen

Simple question.

When I try to open a file with the name text.txt it works properly.

However if I rename the file to text.cir.txt it gives me ERROR.

What can I do to fix it?

```
FILE *fd;
char nome_fich[] = "text.cir.txt";
int x;
fd = fopen("text.cir.txt", "r");

if (fd == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR");
}
else
{
    while ((x = fgetc(fd)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", x);
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: on windows or linux ? double check those filenames

Comment: esp with show file extension off/on in the windooze explorer

Comment: Does the renamed file exist? Check `errno`.

Comment: Use `perror` as it will tell you much more than simply shouting "ERROR!" at you.

Comment: `char nome_fich[] = "text.cir.txt";` and `fopen("text.cir.txt", "r");` looks like an opportunity for confusion.  Drop the `char nome_fich[] = "text.cir.txt";`  and test your compilations/runs again.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("ERROR");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  and when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror("fopen failed");`  does all of the above correctly

Comment: OT:  in general, the letters: `fd` are typically used for a file descriptor number and `fp` are typically used for a file pointer.  Note: `fopen()` returns a file pointer while `open()` returns a file descriptor number

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files and it is missing any function, like `main()`

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for and handles errors

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // FILE, fopen(), perror(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fd = fopen( "text.cir.txt", "r" );

    if ( !fd )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int x;
    while ((x = fgetc(fd)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", x);
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

when run against any .txt file, it performs the desired operation.

Note: I'm running Linux version 18.04